# Join en base de datos para filtrado en laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

La idea es filtrar un búsqueda de productos, con filtros de proveedores y categórias

la tabla Products tiene relación:

M-M con `provider` con tabla `pivot` **products_provider**
M-M con `categories` con tabla `pivot` **products_categories**

la idea es tener la lista de productos que tengan la categoria **X** y el proveedor **Y**

El filtro se requiere por el ID de la cateogira y el proveedor

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
JOIN products_categories ON 3 = products_category.categories_id
JOIN products_provider ON 3 = products_provider .provider_id
```

El numero 3 en el código es donde quiero pasar como referencia el id de la categoría y el proveedor

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: La consulta trae todos los productos 3 veces, y lo que se quiere es traer los productos que tengan la categoría con el ID 3, la cuestión es hacer la consulta que la tengo mala